# IF statement with multiple conditions in a batch file

Tags: cmd

I need Help with CMD Command.
I want to make an Program that will check "Keys".
Like this:

```
if %choice%==123-123-123-123 (
    goto next
) ELSE (
    goto start
)
```

But with multiple "Choices"

```
if %choice%==123-123-123-123 (
    or 234-234-234-234
    or 345-345-345-345
    or 456-456-456-456
    goto next
) ELSE (
  goto start  
)
```

Command above this is not working, so I need help to make it work.

---

And one more thing.

ex. I writted 123-123-123-123 and I exited program. And if I opened it again,i don't need to write 123-123-123-123 again,so it stay "Answered"?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to do each one separately:

```
if %choice%==123-123-123-123 goto next
if %choice%==234-234-234-234 goto next
if %choice%==345-345-345-345 goto next
if %choice%==456-456-456-456 goto next
goto start
```